# C++, Hello World program Including Openssl + Curl leads to 100% false positive alert antivirus

Tags: c++, curl, openssl

Im really confused atm, a hello world program that includes static libs of openssl and curl is guaranteed to trigger a false positive in microsoft defender. How do we fix this, i mean i can understand that a lot of virus maker loves these libraries, but its not a solution to flag any program as virus because they use these libraries. So how are we supposed to ever again use this libraries now?

Any help would be highly appriciated

Comment: It is a bit more simple then that, virus scanners may not like content of an executable changing. Exclude the directories(s) you are building to from your virus scanner and you should be fine.

Comment: This just sadly hides the problem, how would you ever be sharing a software where you had to tell the people using it to please exclude the software from your antivirus :(

Comment: Ofcourse you still have to scan your code (installer) for viruses before releasing it, but you will be building a lot more often so for the time being exclude the target directories. If you feel unsure about it, then only exclude the debug targets but still scan the release targets, and then develop using debug builds

Comment: Signed code that has been installed through a signed installer is generally less likely to trigger antivirus heuristics